# Angular 2 static page routing

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

i build a static page using angluar 2, when i run `ng serve` and go to my page it run like i want. what i mean with what i want is, it can go to specific page by typing in url, like `www.mysite.com/resume` but when i uploaded it to my site after doing `ng build --prod`  i can't go to `www.mysite.com/resume` by typing, it shows `404 page not found`.

This is my app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router'
import { NgsRevealModule } from 'ng-scrollreveal';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './components/navbar/navbar.component';
import { ResumeComponent } from './components/resume/resume.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './components/footer/footer.component';
import { PortofolioComponent } from './components/portofolio/portofolio.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path:'', component: HomeComponent},
  {path:'resume', component: ResumeComponent},
  {path:'portofolio', component: PortofolioComponent},
  {path:'**', component: HomeComponent}
]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    ResumeComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    PortofolioComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    NgsRevealModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

this is my app.component.html

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<div class='container'>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

in my `navbar.component.html` i have button to specific component and it works well.

this is my `navbar.component.html`

```
<div class="container">
  <nav class="nav nav-tabs">
        <div class="container" [ngsReveal]="{easing: 'cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.2, 0.1, 1)', duration : 2000, origin: 'top', distance : '80px'}">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">mysite</a>
          </div>
          <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right item">
              <li [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions] = "{exact:true}"><a [routerLink]="['/resume']">Resume</a></li>
              <li [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions] = "{exact:true}"><a [routerLink]="['/portofolio']">Portofolio</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

what i really want is i can go to specific address by typing like i did when i use `ng serve`

Comment: have you set up the routes on your backend? looks like the server is parsing the entered urls and is trying (and failing) to deal with /resume itself, rather than passing the work to the angular router

Comment: @danimal sorry i forgot to mention that i won't to use any server . i want everything done in client side. i make this before using node and angular2 , and it runs very well. But this time i just want to use angular2 and copy build output to my site. is it possible to do that?

Comment: when you use ng serve you are setting up a (local development) server that knows what to do with the urls already - if you've deployed to a remote site it will still be served by something, and that something will need to be configured to let angular handle all routes... depends on the deployment server!

Comment: so that means i can't do that by only copying  output from` ng build`  to my site? can you suggest another way so i can do that without any server?

Comment: how do you plan to serve a website with no server?! it should be a configuration option somewhere in the server code/hosting company if that's what you use. otherwise, you could try using instead a hash location strategy https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/HashLocationStrategy-class.html

Comment: the front end code should remain the same, it's the remote server code/config that needs to change

Comment: what i mean to do that without any server is i don't want to setup(coding) any server side things, i just want to copy and paste output from angular build to my site

Comment: @danimal can you help me to hide parameter in url when i press resume/portofolio button in navbar. cause when i press that buttons it shows www.mystite/resume or www.mystite/portofolio that dont actualy exist in web server. so my plan is to hide it

Comment: I don't see any way round this apart from: 1) configure the server (it should be one or two lines max) or 2) use hash location strategy as in my comment above

Comment: thanks for your help. so i decide to use apache rule to redirect not found page to my index.html. but if you know how to hide resume/portofolio parameter in url can you tell how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced this issue before and i think its the same case:

If you are using Nginx web server, make sure you have a right rule to redirect any URL to the index.html for example:

```
location / {
    # try_files $uri @rewrite;
    try_files $uri /index.html?$query_string;
}
```

For Apache i do not really test it but i think its the same case.

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/deployment.html#!#fallback thanks i read it in this url too, but i have button in navbar that when i press it, it shows parameter in url, i want to hide it can you help me